# Tailwind Carousel

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to make a carousel using Tailwind CSS. But I am not able to convert some pure CSS into tailwind CSS.

If it is not possible to convert that pure CSS into tailwind CSS then please tell me how to add that CSS in my react project.
I am using **REACT**.

Please help me with this issue.

Pure css:

```
.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}
.carousel-item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}
#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet
{ 
  color: #2b6cb0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel relative shadow-2xl bg-white">
    <div class="carousel-inner relative overflow-hidden w-full">
      <!--Slide 1-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="" checked="checked">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0" style="height:50vh;">
            <div class="block h-full w-full bg-indigo-500 text-white text-5xl text-center">Slide 1</div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="prev control-1 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="next control-1 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label>
        
        <!--Slide 2-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-2" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0" style="height:50vh;">
            <div class="block h-full w-full bg-orange-500 text-white text-5xl text-center">Slide 2</div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="prev control-2 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-3" class="next control-2 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label> 
        
        <!--Slide 3-->
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-3" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" hidden="">
        <div class="carousel-item absolute opacity-0" style="height:50vh;">
            <div class="block h-full w-full bg-green-500 text-white text-5xl text-center">Slide 3</div>
        </div>
        <label for="carousel-2" class="prev control-3 w-10 h-10 ml-2 md:ml-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 left-0 my-auto">‹</label>
        <label for="carousel-1" class="next control-3 w-10 h-10 mr-2 md:mr-10 absolute cursor-pointer hidden text-3xl font-bold text-black hover:text-white rounded-full bg-white hover:bg-blue-700 leading-tight text-center z-10 inset-y-0 right-0 my-auto">›</label>

        <!-- Add additional indicators for each slide-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="inline-block mr-3">
                <label for="carousel-1" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-white hover:text-blue-700">•</label>
            </li>
            <li class="inline-block mr-3">
                <label for="carousel-2" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-white hover:text-blue-700">•</label>
            </li>
            <li class="inline-block mr-3">
                <label for="carousel-3" class="carousel-bullet cursor-pointer block text-4xl text-white hover:text-blue-700">•</label>
            </li>
        </ol>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's impossible to convert pure CSS to tailwind CSS since it is a utility-first CSS framework.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first

Comment: Hello @DevMaster So, How I can apply these CSS styles in tailwind or please suggest some other way of doing this in tailwind react.

Answer (score 4):

First take a look at [Using Tailwind CSS with Create React App](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#app)

There are two ways to use pure CSS with Tailwind-CSS

- Very normal way as we always did

Create a new `.css` file and put them into it.

Then import it into the React component.

`app.css`

```css
.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}
.carousel-item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
}
#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
#carousel-1:checked
  ~ .control-1
  ~ .carousel-indicators
  li:nth-child(1)
  .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked
  ~ .control-2
  ~ .carousel-indicators
  li:nth-child(2)
  .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked
  ~ .control-3
  ~ .carousel-indicators
  li:nth-child(3)
  .carousel-bullet {
  color: #2b6cb0;
}
```

`app.js`

```
import './App.css'
import './tailwind.out.css'
...
```

- [Extending Tailwind with your own custom utility classes.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities#app)

The easiest way to add your own utilities to Tailwind is to simply add them to your CSS.

`tailwind.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: static;
    opacity: 100;
  }
  .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-out;
  }
  #carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
  #carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
  #carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #carousel-1:checked
    ~ .control-1
    ~ .carousel-indicators
    li:nth-child(1)
    .carousel-bullet,
  #carousel-2:checked
    ~ .control-2
    ~ .carousel-indicators
    li:nth-child(2)
    .carousel-bullet,
  #carousel-3:checked
    ~ .control-3
    ~ .carousel-indicators
    li:nth-child(3)
    .carousel-bullet {
    color: #2b6cb0;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to customize the tailwind.js file(i.e. adding my own color palette) what is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

Answer (score 0):

i guess the best way to do a carousel by tailwind in React is by using tailwind it with **Swiper**, makes it a lot easier and editable.
install Swiper by `npm install swiper` or `yarn add swiper` if you're using yarn and start using it.
if you want more demos : https://swiperjs.com/demos

```html
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

import "./styles.css";

// import required modules
import { Pagination } from "swiper";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper pagination={true} modules={[Pagination]} className="mySwiper">
        <SwiperSlide>
        <div className='w-full h-screen grid justify-items-center'>
                    Test1
                </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>
        <div className='w-full h-screen grid justify-items-center'>
                    Test2
                </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>
        <div className='w-full h-screen grid justify-items-center'>
                    Test3
                </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>
        <div className='w-full h-screen grid justify-items-center'>
                    Test4
                </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```